# Recording Stream being played on Android

Tags: android, streaming, shoutcast

I am developing a application in Android that plays out a Shoutcast stream using the MediaPlayer. I have a requirement of parallely recording the played stream to the SD card in the MP3 format

Is there is a way out in Android? Is there any sample code available to achieve this

Comment: @user669231: I hope the stream content is non-copyright / public domain or you otherwise have permission to record it.

Comment: That is in public domain...please suggest the technical feasibility & solution approach

Comment: @user669231: OK, possible approach is not to play live with MP and  attempt to write to SD card in parallel. I don't think this is possible. Instead buffer to a file on the SD card (which will ultimately become the recording) then play from the buffer file using MP.

Comment: Well I already have developed this application that plays out the stream using the inbuilt MediaPlayer. These are
MP3 streams hence the player supports them natively

Now if I have to start reading the stream myself, save it & then play it from the disk, this would mean complete 
architecture change for the application. Not to mention the additional challenges that may come while customizing
the application to do this

I hope I have clarified the point here :-(

Are there any other alternatives to save the stream in parallel when it is being played by the Media Player?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used to do this with the Last.FM player (when it actually worked). It was, however, not a simple means of recording.

Step 1: Write proxy with stream recording function

Step 2: root your phone

Step 3: run on phone:

```
iptables -t nat -N proxy
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -m owner --uid-owner (uid of streaming app) -p tcp -j proxy
iptables -t nat -A proxy -p tcp -j DNAT --to proxyip:port
```

My 'step 1' was written in perl, and rather messy. For shoutcast, there may be a recording proxy already available.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I would need some more details on this. Possibly a help link

Answer (score 0):

I am working on something similar and facing the same problem.

I am able to play the stream but i am having trouble with the recording part, i assume i have to read the stream bit by bit and save it to a file. So far this was my approach for the recording.

P.S. Don't forget permissions while recording.

```
    private void startRecording() {
    String fileName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
    fileName += "/FM-Recording-"+recordFile;
    mRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
    //mRecorder.setAudioSource(mediaPlayer.getAudioSessionID());
    mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.DEFAULT);
    mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
    mRecorder.setOutputFile(fileName);
    mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);

    try {
        mRecorder.prepare();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "prepare() failed "+e.toString());
    }

    mRecorder.start();
}

   private class RecorderThread extends Thread {
    public void go(){
        runOnUiThread (new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                isRecording = true;
                startRecording();
            }
        }));
    }
    }
```

Here is layout:
[Application Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nwVNc.png)

Answer (score 0):

## Or implement something like this

```
  private void startRecording() {

    BufferedOutputStream writer = null;
    try {
        URL url = new URL(RADIO_STATION_URL);
        URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();

        writer = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File(fileName)));
        recordingStream = connection.getInputStream();

        final int BUFFER_SIZE = 100;

        byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];

        while (recordingStream.read(buffer, 0, BUFFER_SIZE) != -1 && isRecording) {
            writer.write(buffer, 0, BUFFER_SIZE);
            writer.flush();
        }

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            recordingStream.close();
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```